# How to mock a d3.json() call in Angular app with Jasmine tests with Karma task runner

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am trying to test my d3 and angular app using Jasmine and Karma task runner. It works when I use the app in the browser but I am having problems setting up the tests. I am also using browserify.

The factory service loads in the d3 dependency (instead of putting d3 in a script tag) which is used by the world map service, this **controller** and the directive (below):

```
.factory('d3Service', ['$document', '$q', '$rootScope', '$window', d3Service])
.service('Category', ['$http', categoryService])
//most of the d3 methods are in this service
.service('WorldMap', ['d3Service', worldMapService])
.controller('MapCtrl', ['$scope', 'd3Service', 'Category', '$http',
    function($scope, d3Service, Category, $http) {
        // waits until d3 is loaded then gets the world
        // data json file and set to controller's scope
        d3Service.d3().then(function(d3){
            $http.get("world.json").success(function(world) {
               $scope.countries = topojson.feature(world, world.objects.countries).features;
            });
        });
    }
])
//the directive is what contains the d3 map
.directive('wmMap', ['d3Service', 'Category', '$window', 'ngDialog', 'WorldMap', wmMap]);
```

The **directive** similarly waits for the d3 dependency to load:

```
var wmMap = function(d3Service, Category, $window, ngDialog, WorldMap){
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        link: function(scope, ele, attrs){
            d3Service.d3().then(function(d3) {              

                //do some stuff

                // when world data json is loaded and scope is set 
                // call render to set map on page
                scope.$watch('countries', function(countries){

                    if(countries !== undefined){
                        WorldMap.render(ele[0], zoom, countries, Category, ngDialog);
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    }
}
```

**Tests** - use $httpBackend.expectGet() to set some data and then $httpBackend.flush() to load it to the test in the 'it' block. The $scope data that should be loaded in for $scope.countries is not there...?

```
describe('d3', function(){
        var data, $q, $rootScope, $compile, $window, $httpBackend, html, element;       

        beforeEach(function(){
            mockd3Service = {};
            mockMapService = {};
            module('WorldMaps');
            //provide services
            module(function($provide){
                $provide.value('d3Service', mockd3Service);
                $provide.value('WorldMap', mockMapService);
            });

            inject(function($injector,_$compile_, _$rootScope_, _$window_, _$q_, _$controller_, _$httpBackend_){
                $window = _$window_;
                $compile = _$compile_;
                $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
                $controller = _$controller_;
                $q = _$q_;
                $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;

                // load in some mock data for http request
                $httpBackend.expectGET('world.json')
                .respond({arcs: ['abc'],
                        objects: {countries: {geometries: [{arcs:[], id: "Netherlands", type: "Polygon"}]}},
                        transform: {scale: [], translate: []},
                        type: "Topology"}
                        );

                $scope = $rootScope.$new();
            });

            mockd3Service.d3 = function(){
                var deferred = $q.defer();
                deferred.resolve($window.d3);           
                return deferred.promise;
            }
        });

        it('created', function(){
            //check d3 service is running
            html = '<wm-map></wm-map>';
            element = angular.element(html);
            element = $compile(html)($rootScope);
            $rootScope.$digest();

            expect($scope.countries).toBeUndefined();
            ctrl = $controller('MapCtrl', {'$scope' : $scope});
            $httpBackend.flush();

            //$scope is logged out with a countries property 
            //but countries is undefined
            console.log($scope);
        });

    })
```

Answer (score 0):

You could get your JSON file with `$http` instead and mock that with `$httpBackend`, then pass the JSON data to D3.

Of course, if you are trying to test D3 rendering, this approach doesn't solve that, but if all you want to do is ensure that the HTTP request was made, you could take that approach instead.

Comment: Thanks - yes I can do this but as you said I was trying to test out the d3.json call

Comment: I have edited the above question to fit in line with your (@Tina) answer. Does anyone know why $scope.countries is undefined?